# How to find the cause of electrified refrigerator?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, refrigerator, electric-motor

I bought a new refrigerator and on testing with neon tester I can see current on the metal frame.

1. It goes away when the refrigerator is cooled and compressor is off.
2. If refrigerator is shut down for few hours. It take around 1 hour for frame to become electrified.
3. The connection is not grounded.
4. Its a two phase connection.
5. Testes with continuity tester on ground and neutral pin on the plug but got negative.
6. Its not static electricity because it goes off when plug is removed.

Comment: #3 - if the fridge doesn't connect to the house's grounding/earthing system, then any short circuit, bare wire, slightly jarred connection within the metal frame of the fridge itself will electrify the whole thing. This would either be a manufacturing defect or a shipping related issue. Since it's new, it sounds like it's time to arrange for warranty service/replacement/return.

Comment: a two phase refrigerator?

Comment: What do you mean by "neon tester"? Does it have two wires/probes, or just one? Also, do you mean "two wire" (no ground) rather than "two phase" (240V)?

Comment: Are you getting shocked?  A neon tester to the frame and what?  If no ground  how are you testing it with a neon tester? It sounds more like a non contact tester and phantom voltage because it is not grounded .a neon tester requires aprox 90v to illuminate.

Answer (score 4):

The answer will be 3.  It's common for appliances to have interference suppression capacitors between the phases and ground.  These will leak a small current, maybe a milliamp or two.  But if the ground isn't connected, that can produce a tingle if you touch the appliance.

The solution is to fix the grounding.

Answer (score 4):

If you have neither grounding nor GFCI protection, then you're a suicide jockey.

Refrigerators have *actual ground faults* all the time.   We can't armwave this as "well this is an intended and tiny leak in the fridge" - it might be a serious and alarming leak.

So stop fooling around with safety and either a) retrofit grounds per NEC, or b) do GFCI protection!

I know I constantly say "don't put GFCI on fridges due to nuisance trips spoiling food", but if the fridge is not grounded, nuisance trips are not likely since there is no path for fault current to take.